# Magento 2.2.10 cancelling orders from admin

Tags: orders, order-status, status, order-state, cancel-orders

If I cancel order from admin the status change to rejected and the item status change to cancel as I expected.

Is it possible if I could move the reject status to cancel too?

If there is anything I can follow please guide or and tips